# Is pragmatics a waste basket？

Tags: semantics, pragmatics

Is pragmatics a waste basket？ this sentence is abstracted from the study of language of Yule.  I want to know why this statement comes into being( pragmatics is a waste basket.)
And is it really true?  Why?

Comment: Its a philosophical question, utilizing a metaphor.  Not answerable here.

Comment: I suggest this is a very good question which might be answered here but really belongs on  [linguistics.se].

Comment: The short answer is “pragmatics the catch-all category we assign linguistic features to when we can’t assign them to a more clearly defined category like syntax or morphology”. It’s the “bucket of handwavium”. The linguistic equivalent to music’s “timbre”. The ineffable qualities, the “style”, the stuff left over when you’ve already objectively described as much as you’re able.

Comment: What is "Yule"? Do you mean Jirel (ISO-639-3: `jul`)?

Comment: @Wilson The book is the Study of Language written by George Yule.  ISBN: 9781316606759